# Django Migration Order with AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: django, dependencies, migration

I changed the name of a model in one of my apps and now when I go to run the migration it's erroring out because the first migration it runs depends on the changed model. I've checked the order in the settings.py installed apps shown here:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'storages',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'verification',
    'comp',
    'direct',
    'comm',
    'track',
    'match',
    'crawlers',
    'event',
    'c',
    'forum',
    'widget_tweaks',

]
```

'comm' is the app I need to migrate first and I've repeatedly run: `python manage.py makemigrations comm` and then `python manage.py migrate comm` still no luck. The only other thing I can think of is a dependency issue. Here are the dependencies for the migration that brings the model over:

```
dependencies = [
    ('direct', '0006_auto_20180420_1937'),
    ('match', '0013_auto_20180420_1937'),
    ('forum', '0020_auto_20180420_1937'),
    ('event', '0040_auto_20180420_1937'),
    migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ('comm', '0037_auto_20180404_2012'),
    ('track', '0002_auto_20180420_1937'),
    ('comp', '0074_auto_20180305_1740'),

]
```

Traceback: 
Operations to perform:

```
  Apply all migrations: comm
Running migrations:
  Applying track.0002_auto_20180420_1937...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 122, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 481, in alter_field
    new_db_params = new_field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 966, in db_parameters
    return {"type": self.db_type(connection), "check": self.db_check(connection)}
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 963, in db_type
    return self.target_field.rel_db_type(connection=connection)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 877, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 634, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 621, in related_fields
    self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 606, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'comm.Cust' cannot be resolved
```

Cust is the model I changed that needs to be migrated first.

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('track', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='trackrequest',
            name='emp',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='comm.Cust'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: please share the error and traceback

Comment: My apologies I've added it above

Comment: Please show the migration `track.0002_auto_20180420_1937` which is failing.

Comment: I can when I get back, off the top of my head a model update where the foreign key is changing from the previous name to the new name

Comment: I've posted them